# Copy all files changed in last commit

Tags: git

How can I export all files that were changed in the last commit ?

Can I get only the list of last committed files is separate folder ?

Answer (score 15):

1. Create a file with name **git-copy.sh** with the following content:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   # Target directory
   TARGET=$3
   echo "Finding and copying files and folders to $TARGET"
   for i in $(git diff --name-only $1 $2)
       do
           # First create the target directory, if it doesn't exist.
           mkdir -p "$TARGET/$(dirname $i)"
            # Then copy over the file.
           cp "$i" "$TARGET/$i"
       done
   echo "Files copied to target directory";
   ```
2. Run the script as a command from the root of your git project:

   ```
   ./git-copy.sh git-hash-1 git-hash-2 path/to/destination/folder
   ```

It will copy all the files with same directory structure to the destination folder.

Comment: I need the modified files to be copied in the same folder structure. Can anyone help me

Comment: Function fails if the files have whitespaces in their names.

Comment: @Spidey I found a simple solution [how to deal with files with whitespaces](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/9499/403553).

Answer (score 3):

Here is a small bash(Unix) script that I wrote that will copy files for a given commit hash with the folder structure:

```
ARRAY=($(git diff-tree -r --no-commit-id --name-only --diff-filter=ACMRT $1))
PWD=$(pwd)

if [ -d "$2" ]; then

    for i in "${ARRAY[@]}"
    do
        : 
        cp --parents "$PWD/$i" $2
    done
else
    echo "Chosen destination folder does not exist."
fi
```

Create a file named '~/Scripts/copy-commit.sh' then give it execution privileges:

```
chmod a+x ~/Scripts/copy-commit.sh
```

Then, from the root of the git repository:

```
~/Scripts/copy-commit.sh COMMIT_KEY ~/Existing/Destination/Folder/
```

To get the last commit hash:

```
git rev-parse HEAD
```